# Is it possible to check the log before a crash?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

In Kerbal Space Program you get a "Crash Log" after your rocket disintegrates.

I'd like to see this log, *before* my spacecraft actually crashed. I can see the debug console by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>. But that's not what I really need.

Is it even possible to get the "Flight Log" as I like to call it?

Comment: Normally, computers write reports *after* they're done simulating. It's not like they have an integrated crystal ball that helps them predict the outcome beforehand. Or maybe I'm just misunderstanding the question...

Comment: Computers write to logs all the time - often in the middle of a simulation, particularly when something notable and/or bad happens. In this case, it might be useful to know that a part of the spacecraft was damaged mid-flight.

Comment: I think there's a mod that will basically start a webserver and stream telemetry and logs from that.

Comment: @Nolonar - have you played KSP?  Polemon isn't asking for a prediction of the future, just a log of what's happened so far.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Per the [control list on the wiki](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Key_Bindings), you can use <kbd>F3</kbd> to bring up the flight log at any time.

Comment: Ah! They call that "Results Screen", which totally didn't sound like it might contain the flight log. Many Thanks!